# Is it appropiate the statement. if (0 != expression or variable) {} in java?

Tags: java, syntax

I'm working on a java source code that has the style:

```
if (0 == var) {}
and 
if (null == someObj) {}
```

or

```
if (0 != var) {}
and 
if (null != someObj) {}
```

Should I rewrite it to:

```
if (var == 0) {}
and 
if (someObj == null) {}
```

?

Thanks in advance!.

Comment: You've come across C code written in Java. Change it to whatever you like.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It's perfectly valid to have:

```
if (0 == var) {}
and 
if (null == someObj) {}
```

It's famously called **[yoda condition](http://united-coders.com/christian-harms/what-are-yoda-conditions/)** to prevent accidental use single `=` in place of `==`.

I personally never used it. But some people like it. It's really a matter of taste.

---

However, it's of no use in Java. Because, such an accidental typo is caught at compile time.

The following would give a compile time error in Java.

```
if( var = 0 ) 
{
//Some code
}
```

Because assignment operation doesn't yield Boolean value in Java. 
However, in languages like C/C++, the above is valid and compiler would give no errors if warnings are not enabled. The above `if` condition will always evaluate to false (0) in C/C++. So it may go unnoticed and give unexpected results at run time.

In GCC, with all warnings enabled, it would give the warning for the above in C or C++:

```
warning: suggest parentheses around assignment used as truth value
```

So this may not of much use in C/C++ too as one is expected to compile with all warnings and fix all warnings. As I said before it's a personal choice and makes no difference.

So `if ( 0 == var){}` is a valid syntax and is same as `if (var == 0) {}` and if you prefer Yoda conditions it, go for it!

Comment: Also a nice way to prevent some cases of null checking. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

In general to write `0 == n` is called a `yoda condition`. Because if you say it loud you say `if zero equals my var`.

It is better to write `n == 0`. But it is exactly the same. But it is read better.

Some of the pros of the condition does not apply to java.

```
if (value = 42)
```

yields a compile error. `value = 42` yields an `int` which is not a valid input in an `if` in java. But perfectly legal in `C`.

To compare using the `constant` on the left side is a common best practice. But only if using Object equals method.

```
if ("CONSTANT".equals(myString))
```

if `myString` is null or you are comparing `primitives` since there is no `.equals()` access to the variable theres no point in checking null.

```
if ( "CONSTANT" == null )
```

Although is only my opinion, the benefit is legibility only.

Answer (score 0):

The first style is preferred by some because saying `var = null` instead of `var == null` by accident would be a bug that would be hard to catch in languages like C and C++, but `null = var` would be easy to catch, as it wouldn't compile. As noted in the comments, this doesn't apply for Java because `null = var` isn't a boolean expression.

Comment: It doesn't apply in java unlike C or C++ cause things can't be coerced to bool's

Comment: Thank you all, that's more than enough. I appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

This type of terms is known as "**Yoda expressions**", because they are "backwards" compared to English natural language.

I don't think it pays of with assignments - good code audit tools catch these types of errors, and most should already be caught by the more strict Java compiler (using `=` instead of `==` was a common typo in C!)

However, when you are using `compareTo` methods, you need to consider `null` values.

```
 if ("example".equals(input))
```

cannot run into a `NullPointerException`, while the more "natural"

```
 if (input.equals("example"))
```

can, and needs extra checking for `null` values.