# difference between null != something and something != null

Tags: java, null-check

Is there a difference between `null != something` and `something != null` in Java. And if there is a difference then which one should I use and why??

Comment: It's called yoda condition. I answered [why it's not-so-useful in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13887559/is-it-appropiate-the-statement-if-0-expression-or-variable-in-java/13887579#13887579) but somewhat used in C/C++ etc.

Answer (score 5):

There's no difference between `null != something` and `something != null`. You must be thinking about the `person.getName().equals("john")` and the `"john".equals(person.getName())` difference: the first one will throw a `NullPointerException` if `getName()` returns `null`, while the second won't. But this is not applicable for the example of your question.

Answer (score 5):

its probably comming from the so-called  joda-conditions where you write `"bla" == myVariable` instead of `myVariable == "bla"` because it could happen to accidentially write `myVariable = "bla"` which returns "bla" in some languages but also assign "bla" to myVariable

Comment: Thank you! A colleague of mine explained it to me, and I couldn't remember what she had said!

Answer (score 4):

I just want to point out that the "Yoda condition" rationale for doing this (in languages like C & C++) does not apply in this (Java) case.

1. Java does not allow general expressions to be used as statements, so both

   ```
    something == null;
   ```

   and

   ```
    null == something;
   ```

   would be compilation errors.
2. The types of `something == null` and `something = null` are different; boolean and some reference type respectively.  In this case, it means that both:

   ```
    if (something = null) {
        ...
    }
   ```

   and

   ```
    if (null = something) {
        ...
    }
   ```

   would be compilation errors.

In fact, I can't think of a *realistic* example where `null == something` would be compilation error and `something == null` would not.  Hence, it doesn't achieve anything in terms of mistake-proofing.

Comment: That's also the case in C#. Mistakenly used "=" in a boolean condition instead of "==" results in a compilation error. Yoda condition does nothing here.

Answer (score 1):

There is no difference, but some people use it for ease of readability in their code.

Answer (score 1):

Point of view of performance there will be no difference, both sides of the operator are executed any way. But for a more readable code second one seems more readable

```
  obj.getSomething().getAnotherThing().doSomething() != null

  null != obj.getSomething().getAnotherThing().doSomething()
```

But if you are going to just compare a variable or parameter this is more readable

```
  something != null
```

Of course this depends on sense of reader.

Answer (score 0):

In java if we compare any, always we have to place variables at left hand side and values are  placed at right hand side...

Comment: I think that is convention.

Answer (score 0):

They are both the same there is no difference.